# URI.parse if the argument is not a URL

Tags: ruby, uri

I have a function that uses URI.parse in order to fetch a potential URL and write it in the /tmp folder of my Rails app.

However, sometimes instead of URLs I get paths to local filesystem, and I am wondering what would be a good approach of handling those cases.

So, right now if I do:

`URI.parse('path/to/file/system').open`, I get:

```
NoMethodError: private method `open' called for #<URI::Generic:0x007fae01f06c00>
```

So, that is not what I am looking for. Anyway to be able to know if the given argument is a real URL or not?

Thanks

Comment: `open('path/to/file/system')` maybe?

Comment: Yes, but how do I manage if it's an existing URL or not, in oder to know if I need to do URI.parse('url) or open('path')

Comment: `URI.parse('path/to/file/system').open rescue do_something`, or you explicitly `rescue` `NoMethodError`

Comment: Yes.. I am also not seeing any option without exception handling..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind trusting a regular expression:

```
case arg
when URI::regexp
  URI.parse(arg).open
else
  # do something else
end
```